How does one find out if a multichannel digital oscilloscope is doing real time sampling?
By "real time" I mean the time interval between samples is not subject to jitter.
Economies of hardware design may cut corners and allow asynchronous access to sample memory and other hardware channels in creating the fiction of multiple channels.   As a result the round-robin servicing of all channels may encounter statistical jitter.  I would like to at least be able to determine that the digital oscilloscope I am purchasing has statistics within the bounds of my application.
Before describing my application, I'm posting this question here (after having already asked the manufacturers directly) because I'm not sure what terminology I should use in asking about such things -- or even if there is a terminology for what I'm interested in asking about.  e.g. I hesitated to use the word  "jitter" above because to the extent it is a correct choice of term, it nevertheless requires an adjective of some sort to discriminate between the sense in which I mean it and the more general sense.  "digital process induced jitter" seems pretty unweildy.  And I'm not even sure that finding the correct terminology is the right strategy.
My particular application:
3 channels, two of which are 19kHz sine waves (FM pilot signal indicating stereo) and one of which is 60Hz sine wave (0 centered).  I'm expecting a phase difference between the two pilot wave channels that is a function of the 60Hz sine wave.
I'd like to tell the digital scope to sample at 5Mhz leading to a 20us sampling interval, and then use Whittaker-Shannon interpolation for "perfect reconstruction" (sp including bold) of the the two 19kHz waves.  The more continuous samples of the two 19kHz, the finer the phase shift discrimination.  Over that period of time (in the seconds) any contribution of phase difference from the internal mechanisms of the digital scope's sampling algorithm must not accumulate lest it confound this measurement.

Even if the channels are all sampled at the same time, they will have varying sampling phases between them -- likely different in each unit produced, but calibratable with the right instrumentation so that you could place a little sticker under each input. If they are sampled round-robin, then these figures will show an obvious sequence and predictable gap (within variation.) In addition, there will be bottom-up stochastic processes that lend some unpredictability to whatever you work out for the phase differences. Can you refine your question? Or state better what your requirements are?

I don't understand the question. If you can't determine this from looking at the scope's datasheet or by talking to the manufacturer, why would you expect to get any better information here? If you're hoping to find someone who has had requirements similar to yours, you'll have to state what they are.

You would probably get better answers if you specified what jitter (in nanoseconds) is acceptable to you. Given that you're looking at kilohertz signals my guess is you can tolerate huge jitter compared to even a low end oscilloscope, but that's just a guess.

If you do a Fourier transform on each dataset, it will give you a very accurate estimate of the phase of the 19 kHz signal even in the presence of noise and jitter. For a direct measurement of their relative phase, simply multiply the two datasets together and average the result -- the equivalent of a balanced mixer followed by a low-pass filter, basic DSP. It would probably be worth your while to numerically model these processes (using your favorite math tool: numpy, gnu octave, or whatever) in order to understand what you get, before you invest in hardware.
